# Screen Keeps Flickering when Drawing Graphics on Canvas (Java)

Tags: java, canvas, graphics, box

I am a complete noob to Java Graphics.

I wrote a simple "game" in which you control a box with the arrow keys

Here is the source code:

```
package com.thundercrust.graphics;

public class Drawings extends Canvas implements KeyListener, Runnable {

public static Thread thread;

public static Drawings draw;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static boolean running = false;

public static int x = 640;
public static int y = 320;

public static int bulletX = 0;
public static int bulletY = 0;

public static int direction = 2;

public static boolean fired = false;
public static boolean show = false;

public static String colorCode;

public static final int WIDTH = 1366;
public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
public static final String title = "A Moving Box!";

JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2D.setColor(Color.black);
    g2D.fillRect(0, 0, 1366, 768);
    g2D.setColor(Color.pink);
    g2D.fillRect(50, 50, 1266, 668);
    if (colorCode.equals("red")) g2D.setColor(Color.red);
    if (colorCode.equals("orange")) g2D.setColor(Color.orange);
    if (colorCode.equals("yellow")) g2D.setColor(Color.yellow);
    if (colorCode.equals("green")) g2D.setColor(Color.green);
    if (colorCode.equals("blue")) g2D.setColor(Color.blue);
    if (colorCode.equals("cyan")) g2D.setColor(Color.cyan);
    if (colorCode.equals("gray")) g2D.setColor(Color.gray);
    g2D.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);

}

public Drawings() {

    frame.addKeyListener(this);

    frame.setTitle(title);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.add(this);
}

public void display() {
    while (running = true) {
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    colorCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the color of the box: ");
    running = true;
    draw = new Drawings();
    draw.start();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) { y-= 5; direction = 0; }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) { y+= 5; direction = 2; }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {x-= 5; direction = 3;}
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {x+= 5; direction = 1;}
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_Z) System.out.println("You pressed z");
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


}

public synchronized void start() {
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join(); 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {
    while (running = true) {
        System.out.println("The Game is Running!");
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

The reason why I am asking for help is because the application always flickers and it gets really annoying.

Is there any way to fix this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Canvas is not double buffered and I'd recommend using it this way.  Instead, consider using a `JPanel` and overriding it's `paintComponent` method, this will give you double buffering for free.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for some detals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas is not double buffered and I'd recommend not using it this way.  Instead, consider using a `JPanel` and overriding it's `paintComponent` method, this will give you double buffering for free.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for some deatils

Alternatively, you could use [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html), which would allow you to define you own double buffering strategy as well as take complete control over the painting process, letting you control when the canvas was painted (AKA active painting)

Comment: How would I implement BufferStrategy?

Comment: See the link to `BuffferStrategy`, start there, there's an example. You could also have a look at [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html) which discuesses the different rendering modes